# eBay API -- can't print buyItNowPrice using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ebay-api

I'm trying to build a simple site that will check and print out "Buy It Now Prices" for cars. I can't get the JavaScript `push` function to print out anything but `strings`.

The [eBay API says](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/merchandising/docs/CallRef/types/Item.html#buyItNowPrice) that `buyItNowPrice` returns an `Amount`.

I have experimented with the other [Item](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/merchandising/docs/CallRef/types/Item.html) functions, and the only ones that are working for me are ones that return a String.

The question is, how should the line `var itemPrice = item.buyItNowPrice;` be formatted to output a number?

```js
function _cb_findItemsByKeywords(root) {
    var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];
    var html = [];
    html.push('<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"><tbody>');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        var item = items[i];
        var title = item.title;
        var pic = item.galleryURL;
        var viewitem = item.viewItemURL;
        var itemPrice = item.buyItNowPrice;
        var timeLeft = item.watchCount;
        if (title != null && null != viewitem) {
            html.push('<tr><td>' + '<img src="' + pic + '" border="1">' + '</td>' +
                '<td><a href="' + viewitem + '" target="_blank">' +
                title + '</a>' // end hyperlink
                +
                '<br>Item Price: ' + itemPrice +
                '<br>Time Remaining: ' + timeLeft +
                '</td></tr>');
        }
    }
    html.push('</tbody></table>');
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = html.join("");
}

// Create a JavaScript array of the item filters you want to use in your request
var filterarray = [{
        "name": "MaxPrice",
        "value": "250000",
        "paramName": "Currency",
        "paramValue": "USD"
    },
    {
        "name": "MinPrice",
        "value": "15000",
        "paramName": "Currency",
        "paramValue": "USD"
    },
    //{"name":"FreeShippingOnly", "value":"false", "paramName":"", "paramValue":""},
    {
        "name": "ListingType",
        "value": ["AuctionWithBIN", "FixedPrice", /*"StoreInventory"*/ ],
        "paramName": "",
        "paramValue": ""
    },
];

// Generates an indexed URL snippet from the array of item filters
var urlfilter = "";

function buildURLArray() {
    for (var i = 0; i < filterarray.length; i++) {
        var itemfilter = filterarray[i];
        for (var index in itemfilter) {
            // Check to see if the paramter has a value (some don't)
            if (itemfilter[index] !== "") {
                if (itemfilter[index] instanceof Array) {
                    for (var r = 0; r < itemfilter[index].length; r++) {
                        var value = itemfilter[index][r];
                        urlfilter += "&itemFilter\(" + i + "\)." + index + "\(" + r + "\)=" + value;
                    }
                } else {
                    urlfilter += "&itemFilter\(" + i + "\)." + index + "=" + itemfilter[index];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
buildURLArray(filterarray);

// Construct the request
var url = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1";
url += "?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords";
url += "&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0";
url += "&SECURITY-APPNAME=REDACTED";
url += "&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-MOTOR";
url += "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON";
url += "&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords";
url += "&REST-PAYLOAD";
//url += "&categoryId=6001";
url += "&keywords=Ferrari 575";
url += "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=12";
url += urlfilter;

// Submit the request 
s = document.createElement('script'); // create script element
s.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to implicitly declare itemPrice.  I'm not  sure why this wouldn't be working if the others are.   Is it possible the item isn't "buy it now"?

Comment: All items I'm checking are Buy It Now, as specified in this line

    {"name":"ListingType", "value":["AuctionWithBIN", "FixedPrice",

Comment: http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/merchandising/docs/CallRef/fieldindex.html#buyItNowPrice According to their docs buy it now only works with: getMostWatchedItems.itemRecommendations.item ,
getRelatedCategoryItems.itemRecommendations.item ,
getSimilarItems.itemRecommendations.item.  Are you using one of these?

Comment: @Yuval Boss I dont, think so, the line    

var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];

does the searching and finding of the items, as is given in the eBay API tutorial. The field for itemPrice is shown as undefined on the website, if that helps.

Comment: 'The question is, how should the line

var itemPrice = item.buyItNowPrice;

be formatted to output a number?' If item.buyItNowPrice contains the correct 'digits' as a string then parseInt or parseFloat with change to it to a number as will item.buyItNowPrice*1

Comment: Nah has nothing to do with that because you would at least see the numbers if that was a case.  If it is returning null you have another issue.

Comment: @jing3142 I just tried the *1, parseInt and parseFloat and the result changed from undefined to NaN. So I'm guessing it isn't using the right API call.

Comment: Can you give an example of a string you get? If its undefined then you are probably right about API call

Comment: @jing3142 Yeah, using any of those methods gives this as the output. Item Price: NaN, whereas before it was Item Price: undefined

Comment: But using any of the other lines, var title    = item.title;
     var pic      = item.galleryURL;
     var viewitem = item.viewItemURL; gives something like...

Ferrari : 575 F1 2002 575 M 5.7L V12 508 HP PDL PW Scuderia Shields F1 Sport Seats Tubi, with a picture displayed as well, and hyperlinked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the wrong eBay documentation. FindItemsByKeywords is part of the [Finding API service](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/index.html#CallIndex). The [buyItNowPrice](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByKeywords.html#Response.searchResult.item.listingInfo.buyItNowPrice) field is found in the `item.listingInfo` field. Changing the code to the following will output the price.

```
var itemPrice = '---';
// buyItNowPrice may not be returned for all results.
if(item.listingInfo[0].buyItNowPrice) {
  itemPrice = item.listingInfo[0].buyItNowPrice[0]['@currencyId'] + ' ' + item.listingInfo[0].buyItNowPrice[0].__value__; 
} else if(item.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice) {
  itemPrice = item.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0]['@currencyId'] + ' ' + item.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0].__value__; 
}
```